# why is there a compiler error in this instanceof test

Tags: java

I thought the following code would compile and print "No"

```
class One{
 public static void main(String[] args) {

   One o = new One();
   if(o instanceof Two) {
     System.out.println("Yes");
   } else {
     System.out.println("No");
   }
 }
}

class Two { }
```

But it is throwing me a compiler error stating  `inconvertible types`
shouldn't the `instanceof` operator check if the object is in the inheritence hierarchy and return `true` if so, and `false` if not

**Edit:**

if it is a case of compiler already knowing that a certain condition can never be true and it throws a compiler error why is this code compiling

```
if(false) {
  System.out.println("Yes");
}
```

Comment: Because it can tell from the class names that the answer is false.  Declare o to be an Object (but still create a One).  `Object o = new One();`

Comment: @fvrgl : i didn't see that post, my bad. but can you see my edit and provide an explanation?

Comment: You didn't violate any rules in the if(false) case.

Comment: The JLS states: *If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true.*

Comment: @HotLicks : i said "throws a compiler error" and inconvertable scenario won't be throwing any exceptions only compiler errors. maybe my usage of the throws is wrong here..

the JLS quote really made me understood the point.. :)

Comment: The JLS is pretty explicit and to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instanceof` is used to identify objects polymorphically referenced by a reference variable of another class, so if the reference variable `o` is not able to reference to an object of class `Two` it won't compile.

So this:

```
One o = new One();
if(o instanceof Two) {
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

as a matter of example would be an error similar to this:

```
int i = 1;
if (i == "s") {
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

It can't compile at all!

**EDIT**

An example of polymorphism where it would make your code compile (as per other's answers):

```
Object o = new One();
```

because `o` *can* reference to `Two`, so `instanceof` will tell you if it does or not.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that message because the compiler is able to tell that o cannot be an instance of `Two` because classes `One` and `Two` have no inheritance relationship.

Maybe you meant to write:

```
Object o = new One();
```

In that case your test would make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's because you have declared your "o" variable as being of the "One" type.
Change your code to this, and it should compile

```
   Object o = new One();
   if(o instanceof Two) {
     System.out.println("Yes");
   } else {
     System.out.println("No");
   }
```

The instanceof operator is meant to be used when you don't know the type in advance. So when you have an object of something that comes in through a method parameter, or when your variable is declared with the type of a base class and want to have different behavior per subclass type. In the scenario you've provided, the compiler can tell you at compile time that what you wrote will never be true, and does so.

Edit: the `if(false)` compiles, because a lot of people use a pattern like this:

```
public class Application{

    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        if(DEBUG){
            System.out.println("Debugging information");
        }
    }
}
```

Now imagine a large application where this sort of pattern is repeated in several places. If the compiler would refuse to compile this, it would be much harder to switch from and to DEBUG mode.

In my earlier explanation, maybe I shouldn't have used the words "the compiler can tell you at compile time that what you wrote will never be true". A better description would be "The compiler can tell that what you're writing does not make sense".

Answer (score -1):

First of all for above program you will get "Incompatible conditional operand types One and   Two" because One and Two do not have any relationship.

To make above program result as True it should be like,

```
public class One {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        One o = new Two();
        if (o instanceof Two) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}

class Two extends One {
}
```

Here, One is parent and Two is child. Parent referring to child object there fore instance of operator will return true.

Comment: im not trying to print "Yes"

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment there is no relationship of parent and child. For using instanceOf there should be some relationship between reference type and Object.                                                        And here there is no relationship between One and Two.